# How to get the response of oAuth in windows service using Box API

Tags: box-api

I am working on a windows service, where i need to get the access token for box.com. I am passing redirect URL and other params. But the response is redirecting to redirect URL. Please help me to handle this in windows application.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're redirecting to a URI with the `https` scheme, and IE (or Chrome, etc) is registered to handle requests for that scheme.  You might try [registering a custom scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (e.g. `pradeep`) for your application.  Then create a redirect URI using that scheme, such as `pradeep:authorize`.  When the browser redirects to `pradeep:authorize`, your application will be invoked with that URI as an argument, along with the parameters in the query string.

Comment: Hi John,

I am trying to use box-csharp-sdk-v2. Here i need to pass clientID, client Secret, Access token and Refresh Token. I have clientId and client Secret. Please provide me more information on how to get access token and refresh token using the same application (box-csharp-sdk-v2).